# LightFace modal plug-in and width & height issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mootools

i am working with LightFace and it is working fine. i am fetching data from server side and assign data into LightFace  dialog but the problem is dialog's height and width is not getting bigger according to the content size. so please guide me what i need to rectify in the code. i have given little part of my code. i need that the dialog should grow & shrink according to the content size. please guide me with little code. thanks

```
 var modal = "";
    var sHtml = "";

    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#btnFeedback1").click(function () {
            var modal = new LightFace({
                draggable: true,
                height: 200,
                width: 300,
                title: 'My Profile',
                content: '<div class="BusyStyles"><div>',
                buttons: [
                { title: 'OK', event: function () {
                    if (Validate()) {
                        if (Save()) {
                            this.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                },
                { title: 'Close', event: function () { this.close(); } }
            ]
            }).open();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Dialog_LightFace.aspx/GetHtml",
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    sHtml = data.d;
                    modal.load(jQuery(sHtml).find('#frm').html())
                    //modal.load('<div css="BusyStyles"><img src="images/fbloader.gif" border="0" /><div>');
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }

            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could, please try to make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with some sample code. It's easier for us to debug.

I think the problem is that you already open the dialogbox before you load in any content. Therefore, the dialogbox gets set on a width and height, before the content is determined.

Try this:

- Remove .open(); after making the var modal instance
- Put this in jQuery.ajax.success:

  ```
  success: function (data) {
    sHtml = data.d;
    modal.load(jQuery(sHtml).find('#frm').html()).open();
  }
  ```

If this is not helping, try to set `width` and `height` to `'auto'` and see what happens.

**Edit**

Setting width and height programmatically:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Dialog_LightFace.aspx/GetHtml",
   data: {},
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
     var sHtml = data.d;

     // Get the element and dimensions
     var element = jQuery(sHtml).find('#frm');
     var width = element.width();
     var height = element.height();

     var modal = new LightFace({
       // all other options plus:
       width: width,
       height: height
     });
     modal.load(element.html()).open();
   },
   error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert(textStatus);
   }
});
```

This code might need a little tweaking, because I'm writing this directly, but this illustrates how it should be able to work.

Comment: thanks for your tips but can't i set height and width programatically after detecting content size?

Comment: Of course that's possible with the .width() and .height() function jQuery provides. But that means that you first must do the request, before getting a LightFace instance. I will edit my post to illustrate.

Comment: thanks for ur help...but i asked can i set height & width after modal.load(element.html()).open();
this line. the way u write the code...here content will be directly shown in modal after fetching data from server side function. my intention was that i want to show modal dialog with busy icon when i will be fetching data from server side and when data will be available at client then i will put that data into dialog. please guide me.......thanks

Comment: Then it's not possible to set it programmatically because the content is not loaded before and there is just no way to get the width and height then. But, width:'auto' and height:'auto' should do the trick in that case. Then the content will adjust according to the width and height of the content that gets loaded.

Comment: when content set after fetching data from serverside then i want that content load into this modal with fade-in effect. please guide thanks.

Comment: i found that height and width is 0...var element = jQuery(sHtml).find('#frm');
     var width = element.width();
     var height = element.height();
i use ur code but did not work....i check html is coming.

Comment: LightFace has fadeDuration and fadeDelay to set a time value for the duration and delay of a fadeIn effect. If you want the content itself to fade in, that should be easy with: `fadeIn()` http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ I don't use jQuery on a regular basis, but it shouldn't be too difficult to integrate this.

Comment: i tried to do it like modal.load(jQuery(sHtml).find('#frm').fadein().html())...but got no effect.....can u please help...where i am worng.